# Mysql select if only all sizes equal 0

Tags: mysql

I have some mysql tables:

```
`items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id_p` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
...
)

`items_sizes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `size_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
...
)
```

And i need to select items which only have items_sizes.count < 1 and not items which have at least count > 1

Here is sql query:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT `items`.* 
FROM 
  (`items2`) 
  LEFT JOIN `items_sizes` ON  items_sizes`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`
WHERE ... 
  AND `items_sizes`.`item_id` = items.id 
  AND `items_sizes`.`count` < 1
GROUP BY `items`.`id` 
ORDER BY `items`.`id` desc
LIMIT 30
```

But it does not work... May be i need If statement ?

---

SOLVED! JUST with SUM and HAVING

```
SELECT DISTINCT `items`.*, sum(items_sizes.count)
FROM (`items`) 
LEFT JOIN `items_sizes` ON `items_sizes`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` 
WHERE ...
GROUP BY `items`.`id` 
having sum(items_sizes.count)=0
ORDER BY `items`.`id` desc LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table name `items2` in your `FROM` clause is a typo or the `items.*` is a typo and should be `items2.*`...

You have no aggregate functions (`SUM(), COUNT(), AVG()`), so there is no need for the `GROUP BY`. It also appears you have mixed the `WHERE` clause up with the `ON` clause used in your `JOIN`.  The first `WHERE` condition should not be there:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT items2.* 
FROM 
  items2
  LEFT JOIN items_sizes ON  items2.id = items_sizes.item_id
WHERE ... 
  AND items_sizes.count < 1
ORDER BY items2.id desc
LIMIT 30
```

Note that the part of your `WHERE` clause that we don't see (`WHERE ...`) might be significant here as well...

The `LEFT JOIN` is probably unnecessary, and can just be a `JOIN` because the `items_sizes.count < 1` will eliminate the `NULL` values the `LEFT JOIN` would have returned anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT * 
FROM 
  `items`
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `items_sizes`
    WHERE
          `items_sizes`.`item_id` = `items`.`id`
      AND `items_sizes`.`count` > 0
  )
  -- ...
ORDER BY `id` desc
LIMIT 30
```